# Why does my computer frequently fail to wake up?

Tags: windows-8, sleep, dell-xps, wake-up

My computer frequently fails to wake up. I press the keyboard or mouse but it just sits there. The monitor is off. I have a Dell XPS 8500, have all the latest drivers according to

http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/us/en/19/servicetag/SERVICETAGHERE

running Windows 8, which has all the latest critical patches according to Windows Update. I ran a memory test with [Memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) overnight without problems. I ran [WhoCrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed) and this was the report it generated.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Welcome to WhoCrashed (HOME EDITION) v 4.02
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

This program checks for drivers which have been crashing your computer. If your computer has displayed a blue screen of death, suddenly rebooted or shut down then this program will help you find the root cause and possibly a solution. 

Whenever a computer suddenly reboots without displaying any notice or blue screen of death, the first thing that is often thought about is a hardware failure. In reality, on Windows most crashes are caused by malfunctioning device drivers and kernel modules. In case of a kernel error, many computers do not show a blue screen unless they are configured for this. Instead these systems suddenly reboot without any notice. 

This program will analyze your crash dumps with the single click of a button. It will tell you what drivers are likely to be responsible for crashing your computer. It will report a conclusion which offers suggestions on how to proceed in any situation while the analysis report will display internet links which will help you further troubleshoot any detected problems. 

To obtain technical support visit www.resplendence.com/support

Click here to check if you have the latest version or if an update is available. 

Just click the Analyze button for a comprehensible report ...



--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Home Edition Notice
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

This version of WhoCrashed is free for use at home only. If you would like to use this software at work or in a commercial environment you should get the professional edition of WhoCrashed which also allows analysis of crashdumps on remote drives and computers on the network and offers a range of additional features.

Click here for more information on the professional edition.
Click here to buy the the professional edition of WhoCrashed.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
System Information (local)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

computer name: XPS
windows version: Windows 8 , 6.2, build: 9200
windows dir: C:\windows
CPU: GenuineIntel Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz Intel586, level: 6
8 logical processors, active mask: 255
RAM: 8549019648 total
VM: 2147352576, free: 1936363520




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Crash Dump Analysis
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Crash dump directory: C:\windows\Minidump

Crash dumps are enabled on your computer.

On Mon 9/23/2013 4:02:34 PM GMT your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\windows\Minidump\092313-308031-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: ndis.sys (ndis+0xAEE0F) 
Bugcheck code: 0x3B (0xC0000005, 0xFFFFF880018E7E0F, 0xFFFFF8801B3B08B0, 0x0)
Error: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
file path: C:\windows\system32\drivers\ndis.sys
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: NDIS 6.30 driver
Bug check description: This indicates that an exception happened while executing a routine that transitions from non-privileged code to privileged code. 
This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a hardware problem. 
The crash took place in a standard Microsoft module. Your system configuration may be incorrect. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver on your system that cannot be identified at this time. 



On Mon 9/23/2013 4:02:34 PM GMT your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\windows\memory.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: ntdll.sys (ntdll!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0xA) 
Bugcheck code: 0x3B (0xC0000005, 0xFFFFF880018E7E0F, 0xFFFFF8801B3B08B0, 0x0)
Error: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
Bug check description: This indicates that an exception happened while executing a routine that transitions from non-privileged code to privileged code. 
This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a hardware problem. 
A third party driver was identified as the probable root cause of this system error. It is suggested you look for an update for the following driver: ntdll.sys . 
Google query: ntdll.sys SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION



On Fri 8/30/2013 1:41:18 AM GMT your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\windows\Minidump\082913-64781-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: wdf01000.sys (Wdf01000+0x1C028) 
Bugcheck code: 0x1000007E (0xFFFFFFFF80000003, 0xFFFFF801BDE66D10, 0xFFFFF88000986408, 0xFFFFF88000985C40)
Error: SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M
file path: C:\windows\system32\drivers\wdf01000.sys
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: Kernel Mode Driver Framework Runtime
Bug check description: This indicates that a system thread generated an exception which the error handler did not catch.
This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a hardware problem. 
The crash took place in a standard Microsoft module. Your system configuration may be incorrect. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver on your system that cannot be identified at this time. 



On Thu 8/29/2013 4:32:06 PM GMT your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\windows\Minidump\082913-284343-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: ndis.sys (ndis+0xAEE0F) 
Bugcheck code: 0x3B (0xC0000005, 0xFFFFF88001D80E0F, 0xFFFFF8801D6058B0, 0x0)
Error: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
file path: C:\windows\system32\drivers\ndis.sys
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: NDIS 6.30 driver
Bug check description: This indicates that an exception happened while executing a routine that transitions from non-privileged code to privileged code. 
This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a hardware problem. 
The crash took place in a standard Microsoft module. Your system configuration may be incorrect. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver on your system that cannot be identified at this time. 



On Thu 8/15/2013 4:01:05 PM GMT your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\windows\Minidump\081513-76703-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: ndis.sys (ndis+0xAEE0F) 
Bugcheck code: 0x3B (0xC0000005, 0xFFFFF88001B0BE0F, 0xFFFFF8801F4A18B0, 0x0)
Error: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
file path: C:\windows\system32\drivers\ndis.sys
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: NDIS 6.30 driver
Bug check description: This indicates that an exception happened while executing a routine that transitions from non-privileged code to privileged code. 
This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a hardware problem. 
The crash took place in a standard Microsoft module. Your system configuration may be incorrect. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver on your system that cannot be identified at this time. 




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Conclusion
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

5 crash dumps have been found and analyzed. A third party driver has been identified to be causing system crashes on your computer. It is strongly suggested that you check for updates for these drivers on their company websites. Click on the links below to search with Google for updates for these drivers: 

ntdll.sys 

If no updates for these drivers are available, try searching with Google on the names of these drivers in combination the errors that have been reported for these drivers and include the brand and model name of your computer as well in the query. This often yields interesting results from discussions from users who have been experiencing similar problems.


Read the topic general suggestions for troubleshooting system crashes for more information. 

Note that it's not always possible to state with certainty whether a reported driver is actually responsible for crashing your system or that the root cause is in another module. Nonetheless it's suggested you look for updates for the products that these drivers belong to and regularly visit Windows update or enable automatic updates for Windows. In case a piece of malfunctioning hardware is causing trouble, a search with Google on the bug check errors together with the model name and brand of your computer may help you investigate this further.
```

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have the model with the SSD in it, would you?

Comment: @BenSampica No I don't. It has a hard disk.

Comment: upload the dmp files (skydrive, dropbox) and insert a link into your post.

Comment: @magicandre1981 http://sdrv.ms/1fwHUxl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows crashes because of Performance Counters:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (3b)
An exception happened while executing a system service routine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000c0000005, Exception code that caused the bugcheck
Arg2: fffff880018e7e0f, Address of the instruction which caused the bugcheck
Arg3: fffff8801b3b08b0, Address of the context record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.

Debugging Details:
------------------


EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

FAULTING_IP: 
ndis!ndisPcwCollectData+143
fffff880`018e7e0f 8b4008          mov     eax,dword ptr [rax+8]


CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x3B

PROCESS_NAME:  pcdrcui.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  1

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.16384 (debuggers(dbg).130821-1623) amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff88000bee1c3 to fffff880018e7e0f

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
02 nt!KiSystemServiceHandler
03 nt!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
04 nt!RtlDispatchException
05 nt!KiDispatchException
06 nt!KiExceptionDispatch
07 nt!KiPageFault
08 ndis!ndisPcwCollectData
09 pcw!PcwpCollectNotification
0a pcw!PcwpCollectQueryItem
0b pcw!PcwpCollectQuery
0c pcw!PcwpIoctlCollect
0d pcw!PcwpFastIoDeviceControl
0e nt!IopXxxControlFile
0f nt!NtDeviceIoControlFile
10 nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd
11 0x0



IMAGE_NAME:  pcw.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x3b_pcw!pcwpcollectnotification


    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\pcw.sys
    Image name: pcw.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Thu Jul 26 04:28:44 2012 (5010AB5C)
    CheckSum:         0001A77F
    ImageSize:        00011000
    File version:     6.2.9200.16384
    Product version:  6.2.9200.16384
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        3.8 Driver
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     pcw.sys
    OriginalFilename: pcw.sys
    ProductVersion:   6.2.9200.16384
    FileVersion:      6.2.9200.16384 (win8_rtm.120725-1247)
    FileDescription:  Performance Counters for Windows Driver
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

But I can't see why collecting Performance counter data causes the crash beside that Dells `pcdrcui.exe` causes it. So remove or update the Dell "PC-Doctor" tool.

Comment: Thanks. That appears to be [PC Doctor that comes with Dell Support Center](http://systemexplorer.net/file-database/file/pcdrcui-exe/467411). I uninstalled Dell Backup & Recovery, which was running constantly, but left Dell Support Center. Could not find pcdrcui.exe, so was probably uninstalled.

Comment: es, looks like removing this Dell tool fixed the crashes, rather than updating the drivers. Enjoy your crash free Dell now.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like you're having a few crash dumps of different dll's.

One is your NIC (Network interface controller) having an issue, and it appears 3/5 of the times on this report. I know sometimes DELL shows that the correct driver is installed, but it will not function properly regardless of what they say. Make sure that all optional updates are installed through Windows Update as well as possibly trying a different (probably newer since DELL will show the factory driver) driver.

Comment: Ok I installed newer drivers at [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false), but the version on the web page doesn't match the (newer) version in Device Manager after I installed. I'll see how that goes.